# Android Broadcast Reciever with permissionLevel signature not receiving broadcasts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-security

I have 2 Applications ***signprotectbroadcast*** and ***broadcastsender***

In **signprotectbroadcast** I have registered a **Receiver**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.signprotectbroadcast">
<permission android:name="PERMISSION_OP"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:label="PERMISSION">
</permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SignProtectBroadcast">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver android:name=".MyReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver"
        android:permission="PERMISSION_OP">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ACTION_OP" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

in the application **broadcastsender** I request the **permission** in the **Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.broadcastsender">
<uses-permission android:name="PERMISSION_OP"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.BroadCastSender">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and send the **broadcast** like this

```
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = "ACTION_OP"
        intent.component = ComponentName("com.example.signprotectbroadcast", "com.example.signprotectbroadcast.MyReciever" )
        sendBroadcast(intent, "PERMISSION_OP")
    }
```

I have also made one common **keystore** when running a release build variant but this is not working at all, tried everything.

As soon as I remove the **permission** from the **receiver** block as well as `sendBroadCast` function the **broadcast** is being received properly.

Can someone point me in right direction where to debug why this **broadcast** is not received or how to debug this?

Comment: Add  <uses-permission android:name="PERMISSION" /> to both sender and receiver.

Comment: Nope doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you need the **<uses-permission android:name="PERMISSION_OP"/>** ? Simply remove this and while sending do  **sendBroadcast(intent)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app that sends the broadcast needs to declare the permission, as well as state it uses the permission;

**Sending app :  broadcastsender** (declare and use the permission)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.broadcastsender">

    <permission android:name="PERMISSION_OP"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:label="PERMISSION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="PERMISSION_OP"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BroadCastSender">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Usage :

```
sendBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = "ACTION_OP"
        intent.component = ComponentName("com.example.signprotectbroadcast", "com.example.signprotectbroadcast.MyReciever" )
        sendBroadcast(intent, "PERMISSION_OP")
    }
```

**Receiving app : signprotectbroadcast** (uses the permission only)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.signprotectbroadcast">

<uses-permission android:name="PERMISSION_OP"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SignProtectBroadcast">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver android:name=".MyReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver"
        android:permission="PERMISSION_OP">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ACTION_OP" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```